# Linux Shell Scripting: input character is evaluated for an if statement, but not as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have an array with some elements and in some function the following:

```
echo -n "Select the option: "
read option

echo "option: '${option}'"
echo "option: '$option'"

if [[ $option -ge 1 && option -le ${#array[@]} ]]; then
 echo "go go go"
 ...
else
 ...
fi
```

About the input - if a number higher than the array's length/size is written then the `else` block is executed as expected - same for a negative number - or even `0`. Until here all is expected

But if a simple character as `s`, `d` is written then the `if` block is executed and it is **not** expected.

```
select the option: d
option: 'd'
option: 'd'
go go go
```

According with my understanding `-ge` and `-le` is applied for numbers - so it should fail if a character is used how a number comparison - it should go straight to the `else` block

How to fix this?

Comment: Check that the option is a number. `$option =~ ^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$`

Comment: @choroba yes, I did do a research about that, but wondering about this behavior.

Comment: You left out `$` after `&&` in `if [[ $option -ge 1 && option -le ${#array[@]} ]]; then`. Intentionally? Why not `if [[ $option -ge 1 && $option -le ${#array[@]} ]]; then`?

Comment: @JohnSmith good catch - seems I was very tired I did not realise that. Furthermore interesting an error wasn't risen (variable not declared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happened here is (for you) an unexpected evaluation. For reference here's your original expression

> ```
> [[ $option -ge 1 && option -le ${#array[@]} ]]
> ```

First, `$option` is evaluated. In this case it's `d`. This is then substituted into the `[[ … ]]` expression to get this:

```
[[ d -ge 1 && option -le 12 ]]
```

This is evaluated. BUT because `[[ … ]]` uses `bash`'s expression evaluation the `d` and `option` are treated as names of variables so there's another level of expansion (being aware that implicitly `d=0`):

```
[[ 0 -gt 1 && d -le 12 ]]
```

The first part fails, so the second (erroneous) expression is skipped.

There are a couple of solutions here that you can consider:

1. Instead of using `[[ … ]]` use the older but acceptable `[ … ]`. This doesn't perform this double expansion. But that won't catch the "non-numeric" error when `$option` isn't numeric, so you'll still get an error

   ```
   [ "$option" -ge 1 ] && [ "$option" -le ${#array[@]} ]
   ```
2. Protect the expression comparison by validating that the characters in the string are only numeric.

   ```
   [[ "$option" =~ ^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))$ && "$option" -ge 1 && "$option" -le "${#array[@]}" ]]
   ```

Comment: if `The first part fails, so the second (erroneous) expression is skipped.` - it that part _fails_ so why enter in the `if` statement? - in some way confuse that part ... pls consider to update it.

Comment: I thought that either `"$option"` or `"${option}"` was for the scenario with the value is consider a `String`

Comment: seems in your latest `if` must be `"$option"` instead of `"$option` in the beginning of the sentence

Comment: @ManuelJordan yes indeed thank you for that. (Did you know you could have edited it yourself, and you'd have been welcome to do so?)

Comment: Just in case :)

Comment: @ManuelJordan The thing about those literal strings (`d`, `option`) getting processed further is particular to arithmetic contexts. It's the thing allows doing `a=3; b=4; c=$((a+b))` to get the value 7 in `c`. Just that if the variable is unset or empty, it's taken as zero. Within `[[ .. ]]`, the numeric operators evaluate their operands as arithmetic expressions, so that applies. But if you'd used `[ .. ]` instead, it would be different: `foo=x; [ "$foo" -ge 1 ]` would give an error (in Bash and most other shells, that is (but not in ksh)).

Comment: Double quoting variables in `[[ "$x" -eq 1 ]]` doesn't prevent recursive evaluation, e.g. `a=1; x=a; [[ "$x" -eq 1 ]] && echo yes` prints "yes".

Comment: Thanks to all for the valuable complement. Huge thanks!

Comment: @choroba sigh, I should have checked that thank you (wanders off to think about the best way of rephrasing the answer...)