# How do I get this code to evaluate all arms of if-else? Why does Bash seem to interpret the characters that I input as integers?

Tags: bash, control-flow, bash-array

The last `elif` arm does not get executed:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash


searches=("feet"
"axilas"
"lactant")

length=${#searches[@]}


searchFunction() {
  echo "Enter the respective number to go for the specific search. 
  Otherwise type 'a' to loop through all of them."
  read i
  if [[ $i -lt $length && $i -gt -1 ]] ; then 
    echo "within range"
    exit 0
  elif [[ $i -ge $length || $i -lt 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Your choice is out of range. Exiting."
    exit 0
  elif [[ $i == 'a' ]]; then
    echo "todo" #this does not get executed, why so?
  fi }



echo "The following are the search terms:"

for index in "${!searches[@]}"
do
  echo ${index} ${searches[index]}
done

searchFunction
```

When I switch the order of evaluation and add `else`, like so:

```
searchFunction() {
  echo "Enter the respective number to go for the specific search. 
  Otherwise type 'a' to loop through all of them."
  read i
  if [[ $i == 'a' ]]; then
    echo "todo" 
  elif [[ $i -lt $length && $i -gt -1 ]] ; then 
    echo "within range"
    exit 0
  elif [[ $i -ge $length || $i -lt 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Your choice is out of range. Exiting."
    exit 0
  else
    exit 0
  fi }
```

then the code works almost as intended ("todo" gets echoed but the issue is that
when other non-numeric characters are given it prints "within range"). Why does Bash seem to interpret the characters that I input as integers?
How might I improve on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Linux Shell Scripting: input character is evaluated for an if statement, but not as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690289/100397)

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @they The link does answer the question. When a non-numeric character different than 'a', e.g. 'w', is introduced `$i` is expanded to 'w' and then this 'w' is treated as a variable name, which in this case was not previously defined and so this variable is evaluated to zero. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @JohnSmith That is correct.